# how to draw a path between two geopoints(not specific) in google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have been working on developing an app "jogging tracker", wherein from my initial to final position of jogging, the path would be traced using gps and drawn on google map.

but i am not able to draw the path .
can someone please help me with a code for doing so.

please help!!

Comment: One of the Best Downloadable [Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this tutorial and could implement it very easily.

http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html